# How do I check valid method name for an Object in Pascal?

Tags: class, object, methods, pascal

I have a class (character) with inherited classes (solider, medic etc) that have specific game related methods. E.g. Shoot or Heal.

I want it so that the user can type in Heal, for example, and the program can check what type of character they have and therefore see if that is a valid name of a method in that Object.

I know it's possible in other languages but can't see how to do it in Pascal. It must work in Free Pascal as well as Delphi. Thank you

Comment: Why do you think you need to check for validiity of a method name to do this?  You could do it using RTTI, but that is implemented somewhat differently in FreePascal than Delphi, (in particular for extended RTTI).  It would be far more straightforward to implement your own look-up mechanism to resolve in-game properties and verbs in a dictionary of some sort.  That would be trivial in both FP and Delphi and independent of the compiler used.  It would also allow the names used by the end-user to be independent of the names used in code, which would be easier internationalisation, etc?

Comment: Thank you! It's as much about meeting the spec of the project as anything. My gut reaction was I'm better off handling this in my code differently want wanted to make sure there wasn't a simple solution. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad it was helpful - I've converted it to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to be able to check for the validity of a method name to do this, and it is probably preferable if you don't.

You could do check a method name's using RTTI, but that is implemented somewhat differently in FreePascal than Delphi, (in particular for extended RTTI).

However, it would be far more straightforward to implement your own look-up mechanism to resolve in-game entity-names, properties and verbs in a dictionary of some sort. That would be trivial in both FP and Delphi and independent of the compiler used. It would also allow the names used by the end-user to be independent of the names used in code, which would be easier internationalisation, etc.  It would also avoid the problem which would arise if an in-game identifier contained a character not permitted in a Pascal identifier (such as a space, accented character or whatever).

PS:  You didn't ask this, BUT ... if I were contemplating writing a text-game of any size, I would seriously consider doing it as a hybrid Delphi of Prolog:  Delpi for the gui and Prolog as a far easier language in which to code in-game actions, objects and rules, and there is one paricular implementation, Amzi Prolog, which has a very rich interface for interfacing a Prolog engine with Delphi -see https://www.amzi.com/#apls.  Amzi used to be commercial but is now PD, fwiw.